# threads in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript

Is it possible to create threads in action-script ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multithreading or green threading in actionscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70232/multithreading-or-green-threading-in-actionscript)

Comment: please use the search box on this site. "[actionscript] threading" search will lead you to lots of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

real threading cannot be done in actionscript till now, but you can use pseudothreding to implement the same:

more here: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, real threading is not possible in AS3 at this time however, the Adobe team "seems" to be working on a real threading solution in coming flash player iterations...

[Adobe Max 2011 - Platform Roadmap](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-develop/flash-platform-roadmap-flex-flash-builder-flash-player-air/)

Scrub to 20:58, concurrency in the flash player

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player 11.4 now supports multithreading via ActionScript Workers - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html