# Does Flex 3 support threading?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Does Flex 3 support threading? If so, are there any examples or links I could look at?

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere, in Adobe, Flash Player does support multithreading... http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3007.  It's just not publicly available yet.

Other than that, see [Multithreading or green threading in actionscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70232/multithreading-or-green-threading-in-actionscript)  There are also a [few articles](http://williamjacobson.com/weblog/actionscript-3-vs-pixel-bender-on-cellual-automata/) on the internet about using Pixel Bender's multithreading for data processing.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by Alex [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html):

> Actionscript is single-threaded, if you spend lots of time doing heavy
>   computation, the UI cannot be updated while you’re doing that
>   computation so your application appears stuck or effects don’t run
>   smoothly.
>
> Similarly, there is no yielding or blocking in Actionscript either. If
>   the next line of code is supposed to run, you cannot prevent the next
>   line of code from running. That means that when you call Alert.show(),
>   the next line of code following that runs right away.
>
> In many other runtimes, the Alert window has to be closed before the
>   next line of code continues. Threading may be a feature of
>   Actionscript some day, but until then, you have to live with the fact
>   that there is no such thing right now.

Answer (score 4):

ActionScript 3 is single-threaded.

What you can do is cut the work in slices small enough that the responsiveness is not too affected. For example:

```
private var _long_process_work_object:LongProcessWorkClass;
private var _long_process_timer:Timer;

private function startSomeLongAndIntensiveWork():void
{
    _long_process_work_object = new LongProcessWorkClass();

    _long_process_timer = new Timer(10);
    _long_process_timer.addEventListener("timer", longProcessTimerHandler);
    _long_process_timer.start();
}

private function longProcessTimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void 
{
    _long_process_timer.stop();

    // do the next slice of work:
    // you'll want to calibrate how much work a slice contains to maximize 
    // performance while not affecting responsiveness excessively
    _long_process_work_object.doSomeOfTheWork();

    if (!_long_process_work_object.Done) {
        // long process is not done, start timer again
        _long_process_timer.start();
        return;
    }

    // long process work is done, do whatever comes after
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex 3 is based on ActionScript 3. ActionScript 3 does not provide support for multithreading ( you cannot write code aimed for multi-thread execution ).
A compiled flex application runs on the Flash Player platform. Adobe Flash Player 11.4 and up added support for multithreading.